# How to know the version of PCIe of motherboard?

Tags: windows, pci-express

I have a laptop that I want to upgrade its SDD drive. How can I figure out what version of PICe is supported by the motherboard? (through Windows and not by opening up the laptop).

Comment: Have you checked the laptop / main board *service* manual? These can usually be easily found online these days. There are usually component descriptions / identifiers there, and sometimes even upgrade limits.

Comment: Alternatively, find out what SSD is in it right now and get one that matches that one.

Comment: Another 'hacky' way would be to use pcpartpicker, add your current motherboard, then add an SSD. It should filter to only show compatible drives.

Comment: @MiG I could not find such a service manual for the laptop. My question was mostly to check the PCIe version from inside the OS.